# Scala overloading operators with generic types

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, matrix, operator-overloading

I am doing a project in scala and i am struggling with a certain thing. I am making a matrix DSL so i am overloading some operators like +,- or * so that i can do :

```
matrixMult = matrix1*matrix2
```

The thing is i made this class where the matrix was represented as a Array[Array[Double]] type but i would like to make it generic: Array[Array[T]]

The thing is i do not know how to handle this in the class methods since for operations like +,- and *. It should work for doubles or ints, but strings should throw an error. Here is my current code:

```
  def +(other : Matrix[Double]): Matrix[Double] = {
  var array = new Array[Array[Double]](rows)
  for (i <- 0 to (rows - 1)) {
    var arrayRow = new Array[Double](columns)
    for (j <- 0 to (columns - 1)) {
      arrayRow(j) = this.array(i)(j) + other.array(i)(j)
    }
    array(i) = arrayRow
  }
  return new Matrix(array)
```

}

I get an error on the arrayRow(j) =... line which is normal because it does not know what type the "this" object is. 
What should i do to make this work? Like i would like this method only to be accessible to doubles (or ints) and not strings, if this method was to be invoked on a Matrix[String] object it should throw an error. I tried pattern matching with isInstanceOf() but that doesn't remove the error and i can't compile.

If kind of have the same issue with all of my methods in my class, so i'd like a generic answer if possible.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the definition of the class?

Comment: How is this to broad? Im asking how to manage multiple types in generics, while overloading. Classic welcoming SO for you here... @Xavier Guihot the def is class Matrix[T] (Array[Array[T]]){}

Comment: Matrix addition has been [asked, and answered, before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262284/how-can-i-make-matrix-operator-in-scala/5262452#5262452). Even though the question posses a different matrix implementation, I believe the answer from the redoubtable Rex Kerr is still applicable.

Comment: Thats seems like what i was looking for, don't have the time to test it out rn but seeing Rex Kerr's answer looks like it will fix it for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of Scala you are using, but if you're on 2.8, I found this thread on Scala-lang, and it looks like you may be able to use T:Numerics to limit it to Int, Long, Float, Double.

A little farther down in the thread, to limit it to JUST a subset of those (like Int, Double), they say to define your own generic Trait. 
https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4787

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found in comments:

Matrix addition has been asked, and answered, before. Even though the question posses a different matrix implementation, I believe the answer from the redoubtable Rex Kerr is still applicable. – jwvh